# Close Mainform after Login

Tags: c#, winforms

What am I trying to do?
Open a login form and if the login is correct, open the main form.

By doing this I currently need to hide the login form and open the main form. The problem is, that if I now close the mainform, the application is still running in the background.

What can I do to avoid this?
The following code works as a workaround:

```
    Application.Exit
```

in the Form Closed Event, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: How do you close the login form?

Comment: By hiding it, so i know that the form is still there but i can't directly close it.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this you could do the following:

Instead of Application.Run(new LoginForm()); (in your Program.cs) you should first check if the login is correct, and then call Application.Run:

```
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
```

All you need to do in your login is this:

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (login correct)
        {
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }
```

If the login is correct the DialogResult will be DialogResult.OK and the MainForm opens. You can directly close the main form as it has been called in Application.Run();